# Remove malicious code

Tags: wordpress, sed, find, prestashop

A few days ago I found many infected files with malicious code on my serwer (a few wordpress, prestashop, and some php apps).
I can use simple commands, but lack of SSH knowledge gets in the way to find a solution of my own...

To search infections I use find command like this:

```
find . -name "*.php" -type f -perm 600 -print0 | xargs -0 grep -iHlnrE 'filesman|eval.*base64_decode|PCT4BA6ODSE|globals|b374k' 2> /dev/null
```

Most of infected files are modified in 1st line (but they are not all identical). Eg shorten line:

```
<?php $jefknybs = 'e]53Ld]53]Kc]55Ld]55#*<%bG9}:}.}-}!#*<%nfd> (...) $jefknybs=$ypoqiutce-1; ?><?php
```

1. I thought I could combine find and sed to search for the infected files and remove malicious code, or replace the entire 1st line to `<?php`.
2. Second thought is to find and save infected filenames to `list.txt`, and then maybe use some loop to remove malicious code?

Can you please help?

Comment: If your server was infected, the only safe way is to install new one system from the scratch. If it was infected once, just removing the malicious code does not solve anything and it will get infected again, if you will not secure it better.

Comment: I will reinstal them soon. But I'm pretty sure that removing malicious code is the fastest way to get all websites up...

Answer (score 1):

1. When I faced with situation like yours, on one of my clients hosting I used [PHP Shell Detector](https://github.com/emposha/) and modified it to delete or change each file in half-manual mode. There were some "false detections", but it helped with most of the files.

About Prestashop

2. The main problem as I see it - php files have write permissions (as on most of hostings), but they don't really need it, e.g. Prestashop need these permissions only for some files/folders http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Installing+PrestaShop
3. If you have no core changes outside /override folder you can replace all php files easily. Same for modules.
4. I do not remember any cases when Prestahop php files have more than one `<?php ... ?>` tags, so you can delete first entry if there is more than one. Pay attention - not the first line, becuase in your example there is no line break between `?><?php`.
5. Another idea, if more of the mailicious code are "onliners", you can count line breaks inside `<?php ?>` and delete infected block.
6. Also don't forget to check/replace .htaccess and .js files and /download /upload folders, some Presta versions had problems there.

Hope it helps.

P.S. of course do backup first.

**UPD**

to delete malicious code you can use this line

```
find . -name '*.php' | while read line; do if [[ $(grep -o '<?php' $line | wc -l) > 1 ]]; then sed -i 's/<?php.*?>//' $line; fi; done
```

clarifications:

- find all files with `php` extension and loop through them in `while ... done`
- check if in file we have more than one php open tag, then file is infected and we delete first occurrence of php code (from open to close tag) with sed

Comment: Thank You Sergii all Your tips are very helpful, especially PHP Shell Detector. However I am looking for a way to combine FIND and SED if something like this can be done. For several reasons, SSH is for me perfect way out of the problem (temporary but perfect).

Comment: This is a very nice code. I wonder if Is it possible to combine FIND and GREP in Your code? I mean to run the WHILE loop only on founded PHP files PHP with infection.    

In the meantime, I use FIND to save results to a file infected.txt and then run the loop like this:  `for file in $(cat infected.txt); do sed -i '1s/.*/changed line/' *.php done`  
    
I think Your solution can be much better if only we could combine FIND like this:  `find . -name "*.php" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -iHlnrE 'filesman|eval........' 2> /dev/null`  I'm sorry, but that's beyond my abilities...